# ServiceStack OrmLite and PostgreSQL - timeouts

Tags: postgresql, ormlite-servicestack

I am updating large amounts of data using ServiceStack's OrmLite with a connection to PostgreSQL, however, I am getting a large amount of timeouts.

Sample Code:

```
public class AccountService : Service
{
    public object Any(ImportAccounts request)
    {
        var sourceAccountService = this.ResolveService<SourceAccountService();
        var sourceAccounts = (GetSourceAccountResponse)sourceAccountService.Get(new GetSourceAccounts());

        foreach (var a in sourceAccounts)
        {
            Db.Save(a.ConvertTo<Account>());
        }


    }
}
```

The Source Account service, which sits in the same project & accesses the same Db.

```
public class SourceAccountService : Service
    {
        public object Get(GetSourceAccounts request)
        {
           return new GetSourceAccountsResponse { Result = Db.Select<SourceAccounts>().ToList() };
        }
    }
```

Questions,

1. Should I be expecting large amount of timeouts considering the above set up?
2. is it better to be using using (IDbConnection db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection()) instead of Db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're resolving and executing a Service you should do it in a using statement so its open `Db` connection and 
other resources are properly disposed of:

```
using (var service = this.ResolveService<SourceAccountService())
{
    var sourceAccounts = service.Get(new GetSourceAccounts());
    foreach (var a in sourceAccounts)
    {
        Db.Save(a.ConvertTo<Account>());
    }
}
```

If you're executing other Services it's better to specify the Return type on the Service for added type safety 
and reduced boiler plate at each call site, e.g:

```
public class SourceAccountService : Service
{
    public GetSourceAccountsResponse Get(GetSourceAccounts request)
    {
        return new GetSourceAccountsResponse { 
            Result = Db.Select<SourceAccounts>()
        };
    }
}
```

> Note: `Db.Select<T>` returns a List so `.ToList()` is unnecessary,

Another alternative for executing a Service instead of `ResolveService<T>` is to use:

```
var sourceAccounts = (GetSourceAccountsResponse)base.ExecuteRequest(new GetSourceAccounts());
```

Which is same above and executes the Service within a `using {}`.

Comment: When trying base.ExecuteRequest, I get an error: An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in ServiceStack.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find method named Post(GetSourceAccounts) or Any(GetSourceAccounts) on Service SourceAccountService.

Comment: I guess I need to change from public object Get(GetSourceAccounts request) to public object Any(GetSourceAccounts request)?

Comment: @MarkH Yep needs to be Post or Any.

Comment: thanks that worked!!! And no more timeouts! Thanks as always for excellent feedback!